# click event in Angular not triggering the bound function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I made a simple form and in the end I added a button to run a function, but suddenly it stopped detecting click event, I ran the server again but still no luck, no error is shown in console.
Here is my `template` file

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color='secondary'>
        <ion-buttons slot='start'>
            <ion-back-button defaultHref='/home'></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>New Todo</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <div class='ion-margin'>
        <form [formGroup]="todoForm">
            <ion-label class='ion-text-center'>Enter the detail of new note</ion-label>
            <div style='margin-top:20px'>
                <ion-label>
                    <ion-label>Title: </ion-label>
                    <ion-input formControlName='title' style='border:1px solid silver; border-radius: 10px; margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px' placeholder='Name of task' required>
                    </ion-input>
                    <p *ngIf="todoForm.get('title').invalid && todoForm.get('title').touched" style="color: red;">Enter a valid title </p>
                    <p *ngIf="todoForm.get('title').value.length<3 && todoForm.get('title').touched" style="color: orange;">Name should not be less than 3 characters</p>
                </ion-label>
                <ion-label style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px">Status: </ion-label>
                <ion-select formControlName='status' placeholder='Status of task ' [interfaceOptions]='taskStatusOptions ' name='check ' style='border:1px solid silver; border-radius: 10px; margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px '>
                    <ion-select-option value='pending'>
                        Pending
                    </ion-select-option>
                    <ion-select-option value='working'>
                        Working
                    </ion-select-option>
                    <ion-select-option value='scheduled'>
                        Scheduled
                    </ion-select-option>
                    <ion-select-option value='later'>
                        Later
                    </ion-select-option>
                </ion-select>
                <ion-label>Detail: </ion-label>
                <ion-textarea rows='15 ' formControlName='detail' style='border:1px solid silver; height:200px; border-radius: 10px;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px ' placeholder='Description '>
                </ion-textarea>
                <ion-button (click)="onFormSubmit()" color='secondary ' style='float:right '>
                    Create</ion-button>
            </div>
            <p>Form status: {{todoForm.status}}</p>
        </form>

    </div>
</ion-content>
```

and here is `ts` file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { DatabaseService } from '../services/database.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-todo',
  templateUrl: './create-todo.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-todo.page.scss'],
})
export class CreateTodoPage implements OnInit {

  todoForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private databaseService: DatabaseService) {
    this.todoForm = formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      status: ['', Validators.required],
      detail: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  taskStatusOptions: any = {
    header: 'Status of task',
    translucent: false
  };
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log('Form value: ', this.todoForm);
    this.databaseService.createTodo(this.todoForm.value);
  }
}
```

Picture for better understanding.
[image]

Comment: When you click Create is anything outputted to the console via the console.log?

Comment: It might happen that `float: right;` renders the button behind the "Form status: ..." label. Check the containers. `float` is a bad practice most of the times because it gets your element out of the context and it can easily overlap with something else.

Comment: Alright I got it done, it was the height issue with text-area.

Comment: @Lint, so did you resolve this?

Comment: @Daniel yes, height of text-area was overlapping the button, even though it was visible but it was not working, I fixed the text-area height and it stated working again